# Matching all possible characters in Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
files: test1.log, test2.log.1, test1.log.2, test.log
```

I have above set of files. But with the below pattern I am not able to get desired result.

```
fnmatch.filter(<filename>, '*.log[|.][|0-9]')
```

output files : test2.log.1 and test1.log.2

Files with only .log extension are not picked by this. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your or operators are at the wrong places

```
fnmatch.filter(<filename>, '[a-zA-Z0-9]+.log[.][0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+.log')
```